# Asking for some time or refusing an a project offer

Tags: job-offer, projects

I have been working for my current company for last one year. I have been working on a project since then. All the resources from this project are released except me. I am on a post implementation support which may end soon.

I am in a position where I am not sure if I will be working on the current project for long so I have two options -

1. Based on my current performance, I am getting another project. But the technology is completely different but I am getting a senior position. Also, the project is a full on-site project in a foreign country. I got this offer yesterday and I have 2 days to respond. While I have some personal issues to decide on this, I do not want them to feel like I do not care. Also, I am not comfortable in switching my technology. Completely confused on this offer.
2. I switch the company when the current project ends and look for another job in my technology as there is no visibility of any project in my current company.

If I want to opt for option 2, what is a right way to reject the offer for second project or ask for some more time to think and decide? I already asked for some more time to decide but they don't have time and will pick someone else over me.

Comment: Tell them thanks but no thanks on #1, start looking for a new job, once you have found the new job, put in your notice.

Comment: Who's paying for relocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to remain jobless for a period of time then this shouldn't be difficult. Ask to speak to your manager in private, and then politely inform them that moving to a different country and and changing your technological focus are not on the table as far as you're concerned:

> Hello boss, I wanted to speak to you about the project you offered me the other day. I'm afraid I have to refuse the position for a couple of different reason. For one, due to personal reasons, moving to a foreign country is not an option for me at the moment, and two, I wish to further specialize my knowledge based on the technologies I have been using, and would rather not switch to a completely different technology stack. I hope you can understand.

I'm sure at this point your manager might engage you in a conversation about all this, or maybe even try to convince you to take the job. Make sure to remain polite throughout the entire process. Don't go into your personal reasons - if pressed, simply say "family matters", or "i'm afraid that's private". You don't need to justify these things.

When the conversation has settled, ask your manager what they feel your role within the company might become in light of this development:

> So, in light of this development, how do you see my career progressing within our company?

You can have a conversation about that if you wish, but be prepared for a run-around, and possibly being fired in the very near future.

If, however, you really, *really* wish to leave the company regardless of any other offer your boss might make, then it would make sense to go into this meeting with a final notice, and hand it over when the conversation is clearly at an end.

Answer (score 2):

**This kind of situation is a big red flag.**
The company is trying to force you to take on the new project, surely they have known about it for some time, and have been in a position to give you more than two days notice.  So I would approach their new offer with a lot of caution.

The appropriate way to reject the offer is to **contact the person who made the offer** to you, and tell them that the offer is unsuitable.
They can not force and should not be trying to force you to take the new posting.

We don't know what country you are in so can not give any really good advice relevant to your location.

***When speaking to the person who made the offer, make the following thing clear:***

- The offer is unsuitable, *however you are open to discussion.*
- You would like to continue working with them.
- The amount of time they have given you to make a life altering decision is insufficient.  You need more time to make a decision about moving internationally.
- You are not comfortable with the change in code base, and you would like time to become comfortable with the new code base before you are willing to commit yourself.

As long as you approach this with a willingness to discuss your needs, and the needs of the business, then you have done everything in your power to keep the lines of communication open, and that is all that can be asked of you, and is the most professional behavior.